# Advanced database query in Django

Tags: python, django, orm, django-models, django-views

I have a table(model) in my database like this:

Name|avarage|evaluation

Marco| 9.6 | 1

Marco| 9.3 | 2

Kevin | 8.8 | 1

Kevin | 9.4 | 2

So I need to get this data to show a table at the template in this way:

Name | eval1 | eval2

Marco | 9.6 | 9.3

Kevin | 8.8 | 9.4

How can I make the query in my view?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do this using only ORM. Try using [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

results = ModelCls.objects.order_by("name")

grouped = groupby(results, lambda r: r.name)
```

You now have your models grouped by name:

```
for name, objects in grouped:
    # process model objects in each group
    for obj in objects:
        # do something with each object
```

Passing the groupby object to the template should work just fine, but be aware that it's a *generator* and will be exhausted after you iterate over it.